# How to retrieve json data from Spring Controller using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc controller, that returns me data in the following format,

```
[
  {
    "name" : "Sarah",
    "age" : "23",
    "gender" : "female",
    "country" : "australia",
    "occupation" : "student"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Randy",
    "age" : "19",
    "gender" : "male",
    "country" : "america",
    "occupation" : "student"
  }
]
```

The controller code is like the following,

```
@Controller
public class sampleController {

  @RequestMapping("/tester.mvc")
  @ResponseBody
  public Collection<Person> testMethod() {
    Collection<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    PersonUtil personUtil = new PersonUtil();
    people = offerUtil.getSamplePeople(5);
    return people;
  }

}
```

The PersonUtil is just a class that helps me stub data.

Now I would like to retrieve this json data onto a javascript variable,
pseudo code => var chartData = get("localhost:8080/tester.mvc").
I know that this could be possible only using jQuery, as I am new to it, any help on this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is using an ajax call like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "/tester.mvc",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(value, data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

}
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.get( "/tester.mvc", function( data ) {
  alert( "Load was performed. Data : " + data );
});
```